# InvalidArgs When trying to use UrlCreateFromPath in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to convert filepath to fileUrl using `UrlCreateFromPath()` function in c++.

Following code tries to convert filepath to fileUrl

```
PCTSTR lpszUnicode = L"C:\\Users\\TBD\\Downloads\\index.html";
PTSTR output =L"C:\\Users\\TBD\\Downloads\\index.html";
DWORD dwDisp = 0;
DWORD dw2 = 0;
LPDWORD lpdwDisp = &dwDisp;
HRESULT res2 = UrlCreateFromPath(lpszUnicode, output, lpdwDisp, dw2);
std::wstring newOutput(output);
```

but res2 always shows InvalidArgs.Am i doing something wrong in above code snap ?

Comment: The second parameter must be a writable buffer whose length is specified by the third parameter. You are passing a read-only buffer (memory occupied by a string literal), and you further claim that the buffer is zero bytes large. Where exactly do you expect the function to write the URL?

Comment: Igor Tandetnik sir, understood but can you specify me an example ?

Comment: I have post an answer below wich demonstrates a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actualy write to constant buffer (wich is wrong)

```
PCTSTR lpszUnicode = L"C:\\Users\\TBD\\Downloads\\index.html";
//PTSTR output =L"C:\\Users\\TBD\\Downloads\\index.html"; cannot do that way

TCHAR output[MAX_PATH]; // allocate buffer in memory (stack)
DWORD dwDisp = MAX_PATH; // max posible buffer size
LPDWORD lpdwDisp = &dwDisp;
HRESULT res2 = UrlCreateFromPath(lpszUnicode, output, lpdwDisp, NULL);
std::wstring newOutput(output);
```

And why did you do that

```
LPDWORD lpdwDisp = &dwDisp;
```

you can simply do so

```
HRESULT res2 = UrlCreateFromPath(lpszUnicode, output, &dwDisp, dw2);
```

Comment: @ashish: Glad can help you. Good luck!